# Which photographer created "planet" named photos of chicken entrails?

Tags: history, photographer

I'm trying to remember the name of a well known photographer who photographed, among other things, chicken guts and sphincter laid out on the sidewalk. His collected photos were in an Aperture publication (I believe) called something like, Venus, Mercury and Mars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frederick Sommer
[Venus, Jupiter and Mars](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0936594004)